# How to use to_yaml method in Rails, and remove '---'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, to-yaml

I'm trying to generate a hash in yaml format, but by default, this method always adds --- in front of the object.

```
> h = {key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2'}
=> {:key1=>"v1", :key2=>"v2"}
> h.deep_stringify_keys.to_yaml
=> "---\n:key1: v1\n:key2: v2\n"
```

Comment: So, why don't you want the dashes? It's valid YAML

Comment: These traits creates problems running rake db: create rake db: migrate. If you can, try there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute force, but it'll do the trick:

```
h.deep_stringify_keys.to_yaml[3..-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to cut the first line:

irb:

```rb
>> h = {key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2'}
>> require 'yaml'
>> h.to_yaml
=> "---\n:key1: v1\n:key2: v2\n"
>> h.to_yaml.lines[1..-1].join
=> ":key1: v1\n:key2: v2\n"
```

rails console:

```rb
>> h = {key1: 'v1', key2: 'v2'}
>> h.deep_stringify_keys.to_yaml
=> "---\nkey1: v1\nkey2: v2\n"
>> h.deep_stringify_keys.to_yaml.lines[1..-1].join
=> "key1: v1\nkey2: v2\n"
```